# one-dimesion numpy.sum returns 1

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy one-dimension array like this:

```
array([0.6441961 , 0.36957273, 1.        , 0.4898495 , 0.24318133,
   0.3721704 , 0.3205053 , 0.16859561, 0.26045567, 0.5081331 ,
   0.66135716, 0.63181865])
```

My code is below, simply shows the variable.

```
print(a)
print(np.sum(a,dtype='int16'))
```

It shows like this below

```
[0.6441961  0.36957273 1.         0.4898495  0.24318133 0.3721704
 0.3205053  0.16859561 0.26045567 0.5081331  0.66135716 0.63181865]
1
```

Why does it return 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
res = np.sum(a, dtype='int16')
```

it says transform every element of a to `int16` and then sum, so as every element is between 0 and 1 but 1.0, it transforms them to `0`. Let's change an element of the array to verify this claim:

```
a = np.array([0.6441961, 0.36957273, 1., 2.4898495, 0.24318133, 0.3721704,
              0.3205053, 0.16859561, 0.26045567, 0.5081331, 0.66135716, 0.63181865])

res = np.sum(a, dtype='int16')
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
3
```

The output is 3 because we now have 1. and 2.4898495. One solution to your problem is to do:

```
res = np.sum(a).astype('int16')
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
5
```

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
int(a.sum())
```

or

```
a.sum.astype('int16')  # totally didn't see @DaniMesejo's answer before I edited this in
```

What's wrong:

`np.sum(a, dtype='int16')` casts `a` to `int16` *before* summing.  And casting to `int` does a `.floor` operation implicitly.  So everything in your array that's not `1.` becomes `0` - and then the sum is 1